# ASDA-A2 RS-485 Communication Configuration

Tags: communication, rs485, automation

First of all, I know that my question is very specific for those who have hands on experience with the ASDA-A2 Servo Drive from Delta-Electronics. But I hope that someone will guide me through the solution of my problem.

I have a Delta ASDA-A2 Servo Drive and I want to send control commands from my PC through the COM port, so I have used a USB-RS485 converter from the same manufacturer of my drive which is called (Converter) IFD6500.
The problem is when connecting the Servo Drive through the converter to the configuration software (ASDA-SOFT) I find that it's not working except under the 9600 baud-rate, and it gives me a lot of timeout failures and wrong communication messages. When changing the communication speed from the parameter P3-01 to any other higher baud-rate it gives me an error of device not found.
I though that may be the problem is from the wiring of RS-485+ and RS-485- signal pins so I have replaced their position and I got a total communication failure.
I want to solve this problem and get a successful communication with different baud-rates between my Servo Drive and PC
Here are the pin-out diagrams of my devices:

IFD6500[image: IFD6500]

RS-485 Port on Servo Drive(ASD-CNIE0B06)[image: ASD-CNIE0B06]

Comment: UARTs (which is what it used on COM ports) have no clock, so the sender and the receiver must agree on the exact speed.

Comment: Yes I have set the baud rate to be 115200 between both, but no data have been transfered between each other.

Comment: I know this is an old post but it may be found helpful for you and/or for others having similar problem. There is a Delta product forum in Turkish but I tried Google Chrome translate option and it seems the translation is quite well. The Turkish forum address is: [http://www.deltaotomasyon.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=6664](http://www.deltaotomasyon.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=6664) You can easily right click and select translate to English. You can try the steps listed in the topic and I hope it will solve your problem. Regards,
Yasin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manufacturer's datasheet, the default value of the communication timeout parameter [P3-04] is set to be 0. But the default value setting for the software I was using was 8 msec.
So I was able to access that parameter through the manufacturer's free software "ASDA-Soft" using a regular USB B-type cable and changing that parameter value to the same value convenient with the one I was set in my software. Everything then after gone well and I was able to fully control the drive and the motor with all their functionalities.